# How to run parallel test jUnit5 in spring boot - cucumber version 5 and more

Tags: java, spring-boot, selenium, cucumber, junit5

For test framework were used next stack of technologies: Java, Maven, Selenium, Junit, Cucumber, Spring Boot, YAML

cucumber.version = 5.4.0
Cucumber-JVM now has JUnit5 support and we can use parallel 
I have tried to add -Dcucumber.execution.parallel.enabled=true -Dcucumber.execution.parallel.config.strategy=dynamic

https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/master/release-notes/v5.0.0.md

was used :

```
            <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/RunCucumberIT.java</include>
                    <release>11</release>
                </includes>
                <!--                    <parallel>methods</parallel>-->
                <!--                    <threadCount>4</threadCount>-->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can provide options by adding a `junit-platform.properties` file to your classpath root. For example:

`src/test/resources/junit-platform.properties`

```
cucumber.execution.parallel.enabled=true
cucumber.execution.parallel.config.strategy=fixed
cucumber.execution.parallel.config.fixed.parallelism=10
```

You can also pass options to the JUnit Platform via Surefires/Failsafes configurationParameters parameter field.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
    <configuration>
        <properties>
            <configurationParameters>
                cucumber.execution.parallel.config.fixed.parallelism=24
            </configurationParameters>
        </properties>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And because Cucumber is a JUnit Platform Engine you can also use any of the other ways you'd pass configuration parameter to the [JUnit Platform](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#running-tests-config-params).

Note that `-D` will not work because surefire starts a new JVM, [you'd have to use `-DargLine='....'](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/test-mojo.html#argLine) for this.

Comment: Here is a sample project that runs the tests in parallel: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/tree/main/examples/java-calculator-junit5